# writing javascript in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found JavaScript I like to use but I need It to be written in the html page and not as a separate file ... Here is a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fs6Mb)

Here is how I tried to write it:

```html
<head>
<style>
p span {color:blue;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p>sony sensor 2.1mp</p>

<script>
$('p').html(function(index, value) {
    return value.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
});
</script>

</body>
```

I know that I can wrap the numbers with `<span>` tag but
in my actual page I have numbers dozens of times during the text and this is way I rather use the script...

What do I need to change in the script to make it work?

Comment: It "works" now. However, you're not indicating how it doesn't do what you want it to. Therefore, no one is able to help you do what you want.

Comment: you want to display number with $ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, use `<script type='text/javascript'></script>`. And add a reference to jQuery library.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and put your scripts inside `$(document).ready().`

Comment: What does it means "put your scripts inside $(document).ready()."? where is that "$(document).ready()."?

Comment: YES! I found it... THANK YOU!

Answer (score -2):

I think you really should take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp)

**Update**

As you're using jquery you will need to add the scripts to your page, and all your jquery code must be inside `$(document).ready(function(){ })`, it will look like this.

```
<head>
<style>
p span {color:blue;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p>sony sensor 2.1mp</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('p').html(function(index, value) {
        return value.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
    });
})
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: document.ready isn't necessary in this specific case because the script is placed after the `<p>` element it targets.